# How to get the file extension of files in Google Docs?

Tags: zend-framework, google-docs-api, google-drive-api, zend-gdata

I'm currently trying to implement Google Docs to a website. I'm using Zend Framework by the way and I'm using the Zend GDocs API.

My question is - **how can I get the file extension of any files and documents?** It's no problem getting a list of the files, but i really need the file extension too.

```
$docs = new Zend_Gdata_Docs($client);       
$feed = $docs->getDocumentListFeed($url);
$this->view->feed = $feed;

foreach($this->feed as $item) {
    echo $item->getTitle();
}
```

Thanks for your help and time.

Steffen

Answer (score 0):

Do a substr starting on the last character of the file, going back, until you encounter a '.' (dot)-character.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [files.list](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/list) method of Google Drive API instead, then look at the `fileExtension` field of the [File](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files#resource) resources.